# How to see text labels instead of icons for ERDs in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

The text book that I use to teach an introductory relational database class uses text labels in its entity relationship diagrams, such as PK for primary key and FK for foreign key.  However, the students in the class use MySQL Workbench to draw their ERDs.  MySQL Workbench uses icons such as a yellow key to mean primary key and a red diamond to mean foreign key.  Some of the students find this confusing.  Is there a way to force MySQL Workbench to use the text labels (PK, FK) instead of the icons?

I have looked fairly extensively online but can't seem to find any mention of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images used for markup are hardcoded and cannot be replaced by text. But if you really want to have something else there look in the images folder of the MySQL Workbench installation. You will find all the images there. You could create some with just text in them and replace the original images.